# copy constructor in a member initialization for non-primitive

Tags: c++, constructor

I can get no definitive academic answer and testing has proven to be indecisive; and most examples of member initializations use primitives, such as

```
Rectangle::Rectangle (int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) { }
```

Im seeking member initializations with references,

```
Shape::Shape (Rectangle& r) : rect(r) {}
```

Is the latter initialization of rect(r) using the default copy constructor (of Rectangle) or is it a short form of `rect = r`??

Testing has shown me that constructors can be (are) used but i cannot observe the similar behavior for copy constructors

```
Shape::Shape (string& str) : rect(str) {}
```

For this purpose, Rectangle has a Rectangle:Rectangle(string&) constructor

Comment: Rest assured the copy constructor will be used.

Comment: It would be trivial to check with a class that tells you when it has been copied, moved-copied, assigned, etc.

Comment: What is `rect` ? That's pretty important to this question. You would get the best answers if you show a complete program.

Comment: debugging shows the same hex address for the two. the copy constructor is not hit (likely the copy elision as pointed out by voidstar) so im finding it not too decisive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors are always used in that syntax. It can't be assignment, because you can only assign to constructed objects, so it'd be running a constructor and *then* assigning... rest assured, the language won't do something like that.

To help illustrate the difference between constructors and assignment... `Rectangle rect = r;` invokes the constructor, not assignment, despite it's appearance. But once `rect` is already declared, `rect = r;` is assignment. Assignment only makes sense when `rect` already exists, which can't happen during the initial construction of that object because it doesn't exist yet.

Also, in your testing, you might be getting confused by [Copy Elision.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Comment: "Basically, whenever your object isn't being overwritten, it's never assignment." is very confusing.

Comment: I removed the double negative.

Comment: ill try the -fno-elide-constructors good pointer. not using gcc curses